# How do I declare an express/js req.param that is scoped/passed thru every method on a route handler?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, methods, routes

So I am building a RESTful API to modify MondoDB docs by “`_id`” using the `app.route()` handler in Express (https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#app-route).

In each chained method, I have to destructure the constant `_id` out of the `req.params`, declaring the same exact const four times. **Is there a way to declare/destructure `_id` just once for the entire scope of this route handler to get passed through each method as needed?** I’ve played around with the `app.all` and `app.use` methods, as well as tried out some initial callback functions (`next();`, etc.) but nothing seems to work yet; either it errors out or returns `_id` as undefined.

A simplified version of the working route handler is below:

```
app.route("/posts/:_id")
    .get((req,res)=>{
      const {_id} = req.params;
      res.send(`This is the response from the GET request for Post ID#: ${_id}`);
     })
    .put((req,res)=>{
      const {_id} = req.params;
      res.send(`This is the response from the PUT request for Post ID#: ${_id}`);
    })
    .patch((req,res)=>{
      const {_id} = req.params;
      res.send(`This is the response from the PATCH request for Post ID#: ${_id}`);
    })
    .delete((req,res)=>{
      const {_id} = req.params;
      res.send(`This is the response from the DELETE request for Post ID#: ${_id}`);
    });
```

In other words, how can I declare `const {_id} = req.params;` only once here, instead of four times? Is that possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rewrite it like this

```js
app.use("/posts/:_id",(req,res)=>{
const {_id} = req.params;
switch(req.method){
   case 'GET':
     //do anything use the id 
   break;
   case 'PUT':
   // do any thing
   break;
   case 'PATCH':
   // do any thing
   break;
   case 'DELETE':
   // do any thing
   break;  
}  
}
)
```

now the `_id` is in the scope for all routes